# Dynamically setting the value of an hidden email field doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following code, I am trying to set two fields one of which is of the hidden type which is being set correctly. Another field is an email field made hidden from the visibility and is not get getting set. Not sure why this doesn't happen when the hidden type gets set. Please note that I am hiding this email field based on conditional logic in FluentForms WordPress plug-in. This logic ensures this field doesn't show up when all the conditions based on the preceding fields are true.

[image]

```
jQuery(".ff-btn-submit").click(function() {
  // Retrieve the Rep name of chosen representative.
  var repName = jQuery('#ff_124_dropdown option:selected').text();
  
  // Retrieve the email address of the chosen representative
  var repNameEmail = jQuery('#ff_124_dropdown option:selected').val();
  
  // Set the hidden email field to the Representative's email address.
  jQuery("input[name=email_1]").val(repNameEmail);
    
  // Set the hidden field to the Representative's name.
  jQuery("input[name=rep_name]").val(repName);
  
  console.log(repName + '' + repNameEmail);
});
```

The HTML for the email field is as below.

```
<div class="ff-el-input--content"><input type="email" name="email_1" id="ff_124_email_1" class="ff-el-form-control" placeholder="Sales Representative Email" data-name="email_1" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) that demonstrates the issue? See [mcve].  Extrapolating your *implied* html works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/g8msw5uv/  but without seeing your actual html, it could be anything.

Comment: Does it work if the email field isn't "hidden" (visibility)?

Comment: @freedomn-m, how it works in your code and doesn't in mine.

Comment: Well that's the question - but we can't see the rest of your code, so we can't answer that.  You need to provide enough information in the question to *recreate* (or *demonstrate*) the issue.  (frequently, in doing so, you'll find your answer yourself)

Comment: Yes, I find that it works when email field isn't hidden. I want it to be hidden and set value dynamically. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: So... last time... include this in your question.  How exactly are you "hiding" the email field?

Comment: Included info on how the field is hidden along with the screenshot of the FluentForm settings.

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating.  I don't know what that "fluent form" is that you're using to design the form so I can't help you with how it's *actually* "hiding" the field.  I'd need to see the *rendered* html (and relevant css).  Perhaps someone else can you help you, but I couldn't see a suitable stack-overflow tag to bring this to attention of "fluent form" users.

Comment: Thanks, I got an idea that it might work if I don't use conditional logic but css to hide the email field

Comment: The email is not hidden (at least in the code you shared), also, your "console.log" is not displaying the emails' values (it's displaying some variables values)

Comment: @Sergio, please note that the email field is made invisible with the help of conditional logic that FluentForms plug-in offers, not with any CSS or something.